# Is there an example of an orthogonal matrix which is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Based off the theory I can't see any reason that an example would not exist.  Specifically, the fact that A matrix is orthogonal only implies that the possible eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.  However, we don't know anything about the sizes of the eigenspaces.

Nonetheless, it is not hard to show that a 2x2 orthogonal matrix must in fact be diagonalizable.  So an example has to at least be 3x3.

Comment: They are all diagonalisable over $\Bbb C$, but in general not over $\Bbb R$. For instance, a rotation by $90^{\circ}$ in the plane is not diagonalisable.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is real orthogonal, its eigenvalues must have *moluli* $1$, but they are not necessarily $\pm1$. Also, when you mention diagonalisation, *what* matrices are used to diagonalise $A$? If you mean diagonalisation by a *real* invertible matrix, this is not always possible: $P$ is real implies that $P^{-1}AP$ is real. So, if $A$ has nonreal eigenvalues, its eigenvalue matrix cannot be equal to $P^{-1}AP$ for any real $P$. In fact, every $2\times2$ rotation matrix that is not equal to $\pm I$ is *not* diagonalisable over $\mathbb{R}$.

If you mean diagonalisation by a perhaps complex matrix, then it is known that every real orthogonal matrix is diagonalisable. More generally, every real or complex [normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) (including real orthogonal matrix) is unitarily diagonalisable over $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It depends on the field you are working over. Look again at the $2\times 2$.

Comment: thanks. Now I see my error.  Appreciated